# Angular MatTableDataSource: how to access a position from another array and get its data

Tags: angular, spring, datasource

I have an object in .ts that returns 2 arrays together. But I'm trying to capture the data from the 2 array that is at position 0 of the indica but I'm not getting it, below is my code and some images.

method in component:

```
    buscarAcordos() {
    this.acordoComercialService.buscarAcordosComerciais().subscribe(
      resposta => {
        this.acordos = new MatTableDataSource(resposta)
        this.acordos.paginator = this.paginator
        this.acordosOriginais = new MatTableDataSource(resposta)
        this.acordosOriginais.paginator = this.paginator   
         const teste = this.acordos.data;
         teste.unshift(this.acordos2)
         this.acordos.data = teste;

      }
    )
}
```

in browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzJqU.jpg)

in HTML:

```
<table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="acordos" class="table">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="acoes">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> AÇÕES </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row ">
           
          <button mat-icon-button  (click)="fileInput.click()" 
          *ngIf="row.enviado != 2 && row.enviado != 0"
          matTooltip="Enviar documento" >
              <mat-icon>upload</mat-icon> 
          </button>
```

My question is how to access the "enviado" property that does not find another array of position 0 of type MatTableDataSource as shown in the picture.

Comment: Can you explain this bit more "how to access the "enviado" property that does not find another array of position 0?" you cannot access row.enviado?

Comment: I can't access the row.enviado I basically have 1 object that inside it has 1 array right? so I used the unshift and put inside the object +1 object at index 0 of the array and I want to access the properties of that array

Comment: Can you create an example where I can repro this